# Is there a way to simplify data trasforming?

Tags: rx-swift

There is a function that calls the API from the server to return `Observable<DataFromServer>`.

I want to transform it into necessary data in UI and make it `Observable<[DataForUI>`.

I made a sample as below, but I want to simplify the transforming part.

Could you tell me if there is a way?

```swift
// Models
struct DataFromServer {
  var name: String
  var score: Int
}

struct DataForUI {
  var displayName: String
  var displayScore: String
}

// API function
func fetch() -> Observable<[DataFromServer]> {
  // ...
}

// output
var resultData: PublishRelay<[DataForUI]> = PublishRelay()

// Sample Code
ActionSubject // Trigger for fetch()
  .flatMapLatest { fetch() }
  // I want to simplify the code below.
  .flatMap { data -> Observable<[DataForUI]> in
    return Observable.just(data.map {
      DataForUI(displayName: “convert \($0.name)”, displayScore: “convert \($0.score)”)
    })
  }
  .bind(to: resultData)
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bunch of different options...

First, I would make an extension to handle the actual conversion:

```
extension DataForUI {
    init(serverData: DataFromServer) {
        displayName = "convert \(serverData.name)"
        displayScore = "convert \(serverData.score)"
    }
}
```

Then you could just map/map:

```
func sampleCode(actionSubject: Observable<Void>, disposeBag: DisposeBag) {
    actionSubject
        .flatMapLatest { fetch() }
        .map { $0.map { DataForUI(serverData: $0) } }
        .bind(to: resultData)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

This is the same idea, but passing in the init method instead of a closure:

```
func sample1Code(actionSubject: Observable<Void>, disposeBag: DisposeBag) {
    actionSubject
        .flatMapLatest { fetch() }
        .map { $0.map(DataForUI.init(serverData:)) }
        .bind(to: resultData)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

You could write an extension on the Observable to handle the map/map operation:

```
extension ObservableType where Element: Sequence {
    func mapArray<Result>(_ transform: @escaping (Self.Element.Element) throws -> Result) -> RxSwift.Observable<[Result]> {
        map { try $0.map(transform) }
    }
}
```

Then use the extension like this:

```
func sample2Code(actionSubject: Observable<Void>, disposeBag: DisposeBag) {
    actionSubject
        .flatMapLatest { fetch() }
        .mapArray { DataForUI(serverData: $0) }
        .bind(to: resultData)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Or the point-free version:

```
func sample3Code(actionSubject: Observable<Void>, disposeBag: DisposeBag) {
    actionSubject
        .flatMapLatest(fetch)
        .mapArray(DataForUI.init(serverData:))
        .bind(to: resultData)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```